# update icon for apt-get in desktop

Tags: debian, apt, synaptic

On our cloud environment, I got Debian and now I would like to install a desktop. Which desktop supports an update icon to notify about updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an update icon, install [`package-update-indicator`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/package-update-indicator) package on any desktop.

Description:

```
Notify about available software updates

This small utility which regularly checks for software updates and
notifies the user about available updates using desktop notifications 
and either a status notifier icon or a system tray icon.

It is primarily intended for desktops which do not already have this 
functionality built-in, such as Xfce.
```

Comment: I installed it, but how do I activate it?

Comment: Thank you, I needed a restart.